# Ideal of Clifford algebra additive group

Tags: abstract-algebra, clifford-algebras

The definition of the Clifford algebra over $V$ with a quadratic form $Q$ via the tensor algebra $T(V)$ requires the ideal
$$\mathcal{I}_Q=\{A\otimes(v\otimes v-Q(v))\otimes B|v\in V,A,B\in T(V)\}.$$ 
I see the property that make this an ideal but not why $X,Y\in\mathcal{I}_Q:X+Y\in\mathcal{I}_Q$. I just can't figure out how to cast $X+Y$ back into the form of an element of $\mathcal{I}_Q$. I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not correctly copy the source you are citing. It does not say

$$\mathcal{I}_Q=\{A\otimes(v\otimes v-Q(v))\otimes B|v\in V,A,B\in T(V)\}.$$

it says

$$\mathcal{I}_Q=\left\{\sum_k A_k\otimes(v\otimes v-Q(v))\otimes B_k\,\middle|\,v\in V,A_k,B_k\in T(V)\right\}$$

which makes a difference.

However, this is *still* not quite clear, because it does not adequately show why the sum of two such things is in $\mathcal{I}_Q$. In this formulation, it looks like only one $v$ is allowed in the summation, but actually it should be many $v_k\in V$. The author probably should have written

$$\mathcal{I}_Q=\left\{\sum_k A_k\otimes(v_k\otimes v_k-Q(v_k))\otimes B_k\,\middle|\,v_k\in V,A_k,B_k\in T(V)\right\}$$

which accurately describes the ideal generated by elements of the form $v\otimes v-Q(v)$.  In this format, you can clearly see that the sum of two elements of that form is again of that form.

If you do not do this, then you get stuck precisely where you got stuck.

---

If you doubt it, you should just shed the complexity above and think about what the form of an ideal of $R$ generated by a subset $S$ looks like:

$$\langle S\rangle=\left\{\sum_k r_ks_k r'_k\,\middle|\,s_k\in S,r_k,r'_k\in R\right\}$$

This is what is given in basically any ring theory book (which allows noncommutative rings) and appears in the wiki article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Examples_and_properties).

---

I know you may find it dubious that an author like Lundholm would have not been precise on a basic definition, but then again this thing being defined has basically no importance after the page it appears on. The author simply moved on to more interesting things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was indeed tempted to write the ideal as you did already, but then (as you say) I thought that Lundholm couldn't possibly be sloppy on this. With the more precise definition everything is obvious.

Comment: @JDecou No problem!

Comment: @JDecou You have to keep in mind that a lot of these researchers working in geometric algebra aren't actually very interested in the theoretical background, they are more geared toward the applications. So a lot of what I find in books like this is a lot of 'boilerplate fundamentals' that aren't very well proofed.

Comment: Specifically, I remember one physicist who used several pages to prove (as his main result) that finitely generated right ideals of the Clifford algebra are annihilator ideals, but many ring theorists could have said on the spot that it had been known for a long time that _all_ right ideals were annihilator ideals, and that it wasn't that hard to prove...  That's the gap academia now suffers is the abundance of theory and difficulty propagating the important bits.

Comment: Please let Douglas Lundholm know, as he teaches from these notes and is updating them (see, e.g., https://people.kth.se/~dogge/clifford/files/clifford.pdf for a newer version that still has the error). From what I understand, he is definitely interested in keeping them rigorous (this isn't one of the introductions that throws definitions at you before you can ask why they are well-defined); this appears to be a plain typo.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article [Clifford algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra) states

> and so a Clifford algebra would be the quotient of this tensor algebra by the two-sided ideal generated by elements of the form $\,v\otimes v-Q(v)\,$ for all
>   elements $\,v\in V.$

What this means is that the definition as quoted is not exactly
correct, **even if** the original source is quoted exactly.
The ideal required is not just the set of elements noted,
but includes a lot more elements according to the definition
of a two-sided ideal **generated** by a set of elements.
Of course, by definition of an ideal it would then have the
property $\,X+Y\in \mathcal{I}_Q\,$ you mention.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm actually quite sure though that the definition of the ideal as stated in the question is correct, see e.g. [Lundholm](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5356).

Comment: @JDecou What you wrote is significantly different from what Lundholm wrote, and unfortunately Lundholm's formulation as written is slightly deficient.  But in the big scheme of things it doesn't matter, since nobody ever needs to refer back to this definition.